# Bought a brand new computer, can't run minecraft at ALL

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So the day before yesterday I ordered a new computer (my other one died) when I got it yesterday I installed windows 10 on it straight away and everything went okay, no problems with windows 10.

Now in the first case windows updated itself and installed all the drivers that belong to my hardware, I installed Minecraft and it would try to launch, the launcher would pop back up with the error `exception_access_violation`:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: #EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000bc358e2, pid=1084, tid=4132 # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b13) (build 1.7.0_51-b13) # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops) #Problematic 

frame: #C[ig4icd64.dll+0x6d58e2]
```

After hours of googling I found an article that told me that if you let windows update the drivers automatically it might not install the proper `openGL` setting which causes Minecraft to crash. I completely wiped all of my amd drivers to install them again myself, this didn't help at all. At one point I even reinstalled windows 10 to make sure there could be nothing left of the AMD drivers so that's not the problem either.

After a few more hours of googling a dude told me that it might be a problem within the AMD Crimson software and he suggested me to completely wipe my drivers again, to replace them by `AMD Catalyst™ 15.4.1 Beta for Windows®`. After doing this the `exception_access_violation` error did not come up again, instead my Minecraft now launches for about 0.1 seconds, like it's trying to go full screen and then the launcher pops up with a white screen (it stays white). After a while it'll tell me `Java SE Platform is not responding` and I have to force shut it down in task manager.

Note: I've tried to install the `Windows 10 Edition` of Minecraft to see if that would work and it runs like a charm, never played minecraft so smoothly. The problem is I want to play with my friends who own a realm on the PC version so I'm definitely not content with the `Windows 10 Edition`. The point I'm trying to make here, if that version works the PC version should too right? Since its compatible with Windows 10.

Here are the specs of my new computer:

- AMD FM2 A8-7600 Quad Core 3,1GHz,
- MSI A68HM Grenade,
- AMD Radeon R7 240 2GB.

I'm currently posting this from a school-computer so if anyone asks for a screenshot or whatever I'll be able to post that in about 3 hours from now.

I've tried installing and reinstalling Java 8 64-bit,32-bit & Java 7 64-bit, 32-bit. I'm not sure if it's a java problem.

Comment: I think I had this error in the past when new Catalyst disabled OpenGL on update, I had to fix it via regedit. Try running some kind of OpenGL test to confirm.

Comment: I've also seen people have this problem with brand new computers if for some reason its not being run with the appropriate graphics processor right off the bat. Try right-clicking minecraft, hover over 'run with graphics processor' and see whats running it.

Comment: Please use Pastebin or similar to post the whole error log, and also the output of a DXDIAG.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem where Minecraft turns white and says its not responding, **however** a few moments later (may take a while on a new computer) Minecraft works just fine.

I don't know why this happens but most likely its just trying to load Minecraft on a new computer and it may take a while for the launcher and game to unpack, so the computer thinks its taking to long and is "not responding".

If you have waited for more than 5 min, then I recommend reporting this bug to a Minecraft bug report page, wherever that may be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [alternative](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/alternative) Minecraft downloads, aka older launcher that Mojang offers for those who have problems with the newest one. It should be able to launch without instalations, and needs Java installed for sure.

It is workaround, but more proper one than downgrading whole OS.

Comment: Tried every download possible, i tried the Jar, .exe, .msi, i even transferred minecraft from a laptop (runs windows 7) to my own computer, didn't help as well.. comes down to the same error every time.

Comment: Well, one more question: Are you sure Java uses your AMD graphics as expected? As default, it can use for example some integrated graphic card bundled with CPU. Check in graphics settings (something as Nvidia has catalyst center, but for AMD), what are defaults for running programs. If you don't find Java there, you should probably want to add it and define to use main graphic card (or make default that it runs on main card directly)

Comment: Found the problem! Had to turn off 'Dual graphics' in the AMD Catalyst control center.

Comment: @RobbiedeGier Cool, have a good game!

Answer (score -2):

The Minecraft website have different kinds of alternatives on their download section if I can remember, try those cause they are existing to help you launch MC if newer one crashing.

Comment: I've tried every single version, .exe, .msi, .jar all gives me error's.